# why the concurrency performance of R-tree is bad

Tags: r-tree

In many papers, they mentioned that concurrency performance is bad but they don't give the explanation about why it is bad.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying is not problematic at all.

Only changes to the tree are somewhat expensive and require locking. They are worse than e.g. B trees, because you may need to update the bounding boxes all the way to the root. The R* tree also does a special kind of reinsertions to balance the tree. But overall, it's comparable to the B tree and any other page oriented tree. You need locking for pages you write to.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the insertion/deletion strategies of [R-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) (or R*Tree, R+Tree, ...) you can see that an overflow/underflow of a node can easily cascade through large parts of the tree (also called rebalancing). This requires locking a lot of nodes, which is obviously bad for concurrency.

Instead of locking you can attempt an copy-on-write strategy, but that would also be expensive because of copying a lot of nodes and a significant probablility of conflicts with other writing threads.